# How do I get the react-burger-menu to work with bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to use react-burger-menu with bootstrap 3 grids. I want to have a row across the top of my page that has the burger menu in the upper left corner with the remainder of the row containing a page title, so I wrote:

```
import React from 'react'
import { slide as ReactMenu } from 'react-burger-menu'

export default class Header extends React.Component {

  showAbout(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("Version 0.0.1")
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-2">
            <ReactMenu>
              <a id="View" className="menu-item" href="/">View</a>
              <a onClick={ this.showAbout } className="menu-item--small" href="">About</a>
            </ReactMenu>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-10 h1">Permit and License Documents</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

But what I get is:

[image: Result of rendering]

I thought I would use bootstrap grid to layout the horizontal spacing, but it is not working. Is there a way to do this, or should I use something other than bootstrap Grids?  TIA.

Comment: doesn't bootstrap have a utility class to pull a column right? Also have you tried expanding the burger col one and shrinking the about part one (or two)?

Comment: I changed the relative styles to .col-lg-3 and .col-lg-9. Same result. Also, see below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that h1 class is applying some property that's overriding the col behavior. It is also possible that you need to add the `col` class in addition to the `col-lg-2` such that `<div className='col col-lg-2'`

Try:

```
<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col col-lg-2">
            <ReactMenu>
              <a id="View" className="menu-item" href="/">View</a>
              <a onClick={ this.showAbout } className="menu-item--small" href="">About</a>
            </ReactMenu>
          </div>
// change here:
          <div className="col col-lg-10">
            <h1>Permit and License Documents</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Finally, make sure that you're col size is correct. try making it from md up. Example: `<div className='col-md-2'></div>`

Comment: OK, in order to simplify this, I removed the menu components, added the .col class to each "column" and slightly changed the relative widths. I get stacked columns. I have screenshots, but I have never been able to figure-out how to get stackexchange to allow me to respond as nicely as the original posting (images, styling, etc)

Comment: Oh, I also removed the h1 style and still stacked columns.

Comment: Another good thing to do is to create a simple codepen example of your question.